# Cryptic Family Reunion #4

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in **alphabetical order**, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Hesitate to have a word in anger with Dad (9)
2. Sister will choose between Rhode Island and Pennsylvania, heading cross-country, or maybe New York (8,7)
3. Brother was nasty one on blow before advised to quit all drugs and get clean (8,3)
4. Auntie and Mr. Nader saving lives (6,7)
5. Flip lid should I give in to daughter (7,3)
6. Uncle is on location around Arkansas with kitchen duties (4,5)
7. Grandma has dusting on her list (5,4)
8. Grandpa says Letterman is brainless (6,3)
9. Rant and rave on viciously toward husband (7,3)
10. Mom's zest for life extended embrace to man holistically (7,3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme is:

> Names of spaces in the **board game Monopoly**

Explanation:

> 1. balk containing aword* -- BOARDWALK
>  2. elect + [ RI and PA containing CrossCountryOrMaybe ] + NY -- ELECTRIC COMPANY
>  3. ill + i + on* + (advised -d -d)* -- ILLINOIS AVE
>  4. mrnadersaving* -- MARVIN GARDENS
>  5. cap< + "if i cave" -- PACIFIC AVE
>  6. KP* around AR + place -- PARK PLACE
>  7. onherlist* -- SHORT LINE
>  8. states + dAVE -- STATES AVE
>  9. vent + raveon* -- VENTNOR AVE
>  10. verve containing toman* -- VERMONT AVE

Comment: @JeremyDover - While of course you are free to design any kind of puzzle you like, there are many non-US users who frequent this site, so I recommend that you try as much as possible to choose content that is universally known. In the case of this puzzle, the UK version of the item this question is based on uses a different set of data, making it quite difficult for non-Americans to solve this.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for the feedback. These comments really help me get better as a puzzle maker. It's not just writing the best clues I can :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover - Your clue writing is great!